# Framework7 V1 - How to reload/refresh page after going back to another page

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I have a notification list page with unread and read sign (red for unread) (no sign if already read).

My problem is when user click on the notification list to view it (go to notification detail page ) and go back again to the list, the LIST page did not update (we have code to remove the red sign if already read)

Our code is working properly, the only problem is the page does not reload/refresh so that the red sign will be gone.

I try to navigate on some other page then go back again in notification list, that is only the time it refresh.

here is my demo video

https://vimeo.com/268966053

I try this code that after going back to detail page, it will reload the list, but THIS NOT WORK

```
myApp.onPageBack("appointmentdetail", function() {
   mainView.router.reloadPage({url:'appointment_request.html',reload: true});
})
```

Comment: its likely that f7 injecting previous page on DOM. instead of reloading. disable DOM cache and try.

Answer (score 0):

Framework7 keeps the last page loaded. So the demo video is the normal outcome.

F7 has page events you can reference. If you want it to update a specific page everytime it comes into view, you can move the adding the content to the pageBeforeIn event instead of pageInit.

Alternatively, because you know the Request page is still in the DOM when you go to the Detail page, you can have the onclick of the Appointment Request change the color, in addition to routing to the Detail page.